# First Law of Thermodynamics and Signs

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, conventions

I have a question in my text book about the first Law of Thermodynamics.

It gives 3 situations with the systems for each in brackets:

1. Rapidly pumping up a bicycle tyre (air in the pump).
2. Saucepan of room-temperature water sitting on a hot stove (water in the pan).
3. Air quickly leaking out of a balloon (air originally in the balloon).

They ask for the signs of $Q$, $W$, and $E_{int}$ are for each.

The answer given for each situation is that $Q$ is zero, and both $W$ and $E_{int}$ are negative.

I'm finding it hard to believe that's true. Are they right about this, or is this error in my textbook (there have been a few other errors in previous chapters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sign convention is important, particularly, for the work W. We can define it as positive work if the work done by the surrounding is positive. Or we can define it as positive work if the work done by the system is positive. Check your text book about this sign convention.

With the first definition, the first law can be written as $$Q=E_{int}-W$$ thus, if $Q=0$, $E_{int}$ and $W$ will have the same sign (i.e. if one is negative, the other will be negative).

For the first case, because it is a rapid process, there is no time for heat transfer and thus $Q=0$. The surrounding does positive work (when you pump or compress air) so the $W \gt 0$. And $E_{int} \gt 0$ according to the first law, which is true as the air temperature will increase as you can guess.

For the second case, I think there is heat transfer to the water from the hot stove. So $Q\gt 0$. There is no work done by anything. Thus $E_{int} \gt 0$, which is true as the water temperature will increase.

For the third situation, again, because it is a quick process, we can assume $Q=0$. For this case, air volume increases and thus $W \lt 0$ and $E_{int} \lt 0$. This is true as the air temperature will decrease during the expansion process.

Comment: Thank you, that's the same as what I got when I tried the question.  It's a bit frustrating when I'm trying to learn to get the signs around the right way and my textbook has the wrong answers :(